# Cannot move logs file in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, azure, windows-server-2012-r2

Environment details:

I recently migrated on **premise Windows 2012 R2 server to Azure cloud**. Once migrated I enabled Azure update management and backup for the migrated virtual machine. NLA (Network level authentication) is disabled for this machine.

Problem:

I am trying to move logs files (**C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs**) in the virtual machine to another location to mitigate disk capacity. But when I move it gives me this error "**the action cannot be completed because the file is open in dhcp client**". **But I can copy those files in to another location while I cannot move or delete.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was, disbaled the "Windows event log service" and moved the files ( cut and paste ) then enabled the service again. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know the rootcause but when I had the same error message with files I wanted to delete, a restart of "Windows Event Log" service worked